# tkinter grid manager not working, columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Python version 2.7 (I know it's dated)
I have searched throught several answers and haven't found a solution. I'm trying to get this label :

```
w = Label(root, text="This label", fg="red", font=("Helvetica", 16))
w.grid(row=5, column=20)
```

to basically any other column than the one it is in (the center). Simply put the rows are working and the columns are not.

This is the script:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Title:D")

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 250))

photo = PhotoImage(file="spaz.gif")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.grid(row=1, column=1)

w = Label(root, text="This label", fg="red", font=("Helvetica", 16))
w.grid(row=5, column=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there anything _in_ those other columns? Tkinter geometry managers will expand or shrink their rows and columns as needed to fit the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grid_columnconfigure to show empty columns.  This shows column 2

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Title:D")

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 300))

##photo = PhotoImage(file="spaz.gif")
label = Label(root, text="Label 1")
label.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

w = Label(root, text="This label", fg="red", font=("Helvetica", 16))
w.grid(row=5, column=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Rows and columns that are empty have a size of zero. The code is working exactly like it's designed to work. The label *is* in column 20, it's just that columns 0 and 2-19 are invisible.